# Change focus when typing date into datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker, focus

When I enter '01' into the month field or 01, 02 or 03 into the day field of my datepicker the focus does not change to the next field. It will if I press the tab key but I would like it to change as soon as the user enters two digits into the field. Please advise.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle and post it here. Easier to debug than create afresh :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery to do this, please take a look :)

HTML:

```
Month: <input type='text' id='month' />
Year: <input type='text' id='year' />
```

JS:

```
var timeout;
$('#month').on('keyup', function() {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        $('#year').focus();
    }, 500);
});
```

This's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f6tZ4/)

Answer (score 0):

Forking Stiger's answer, I ended up with this code that does what you asked for: focus on next input when day or month field has 2 digits (using jquery) :

http://jsfiddle.net/dr3c1k5r/

*html*

```
Day: <input type='number' id='day' />
Month: <input type='number' id='month' />
Year: <input type='number' id='year' />
```

*js*

```
$('#day, #month').on('keyup', function() {
  if ($(this).val().length >=2) {
    $(this).next(":input").focus();
  }
});
```